# Would the cheats have effect after we restart the world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

*Hello Everyone!*

I would like to know that if we start a world without cheats in Minecraft Java Edition 1.16 and after that we start a LAN world with cheats from the settings and we use some commands such as keepInventory true.

Then we quit to title screen and close the game. After that when we again start the game and thereafter the world, the cheats would automatically turn off. Would the cheats/commands we have already used like the one given above have any effect on the world. Like would our invest keep itself even if we die, or all the commands used will be reset?

I searched everywhere but the only answer I got is that 'How to turn on cheats after starting the world'
.
Any help would be appreciated...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, cheats that you use do save. The only thing you need to turn on every time you load up that world, is to start a LAN world to be able to use commands again

Comment: So that means that cheats do have effect even if it is not an LAN world after we start again...

Comment: Yes, for example if you change to creative mode in LAN world, then host closes that world, you'll still have creative mode after joining